# SQL: How to select variable value?

Tags: mysql

I have a query

```
INSERT INTO ... SET ....; 
SET @last_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
INSERT INTO ... SET .... ,item_id = @last_id;
INSERT INTO ... SET .... ,item_id = @last_id;
```

And i want to output to result value of variable. for example:

```
SELECT @last_id as ID;
```

**query:**

```
INSERT INTO `targets` SET `name` = '123';
SET @target_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
SELECT @target_id as id;
```

Comment: The query (script) is correct. What was wrong?

Comment: So, where is the part of PHP or PDO?

Comment: It's PDO, i cant fetch results, using fetchAll(), function returns zero

Comment: Please show table structure - CREATE TABLE `targets`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a query, but rather a set of queries.
Just run them one by one in order.

Comment: For my pity, i can do only one SQL query for every user request.

Comment: @Ozerich Why are you limited?

Comment: i should use framework, what use for every request only one PDO Command.

Comment: Well, your question should be closed as a "Too localized" then.

Comment: @Ozerich You should not be using framework that opens separate connection for _every_ query. Anyway, since you're using PDO it has method [`lastInsertId`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php).